# C# UWP KeyDown event e.Handled strange behavier

Tags: uwp

I want to enable only certain keys in UWP TextBox element. But setting `e.Handled = false` not helps. All keys accepted.

Similar application in WPF works.

How to solve this problem?

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" KeyDown="TextKeyDown" Height="32" Width="579"/>
    </Grid>
```

C#

```
private void TextKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString(), "[0-9]"))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("number");
            }
            else e.Handled = true;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input to the TextBox isn't coming directly through the Key events, and in many cases text input doesn't involves key events at all (think IMEs, auto-complete, on-screen-keyboards, ink input, speech recognition, etc.)

The [TextChanging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.textchanging) and [TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.textchanged) events will fire regardless of the origin of the text and so are better place to implement your filter.

There are pre-built filtering extensions in the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/) that may suit you rather than rolling your own. Check out [TextBoxMask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxmask) and [TextBoxRegex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxregex).